# Interface method to measure loss tangent of a leaky capacitor

Tags: capacitor, sensor

I have a sensor which functions essentially as a leaky capacitor. The resistance between electrodes with a dielectric in between is the measured parameter. The capacitive reactance is large, on the order of 10e3 to 10e6 ohms, however the resistive component is small, on the order of 100 micro ohms. I want to measure the loss tangent of the capacitor. To do this I’m going for a Schering bridge, then an amplifier circuit. Is this the best way to go about this problem? The bridge values have to be very precise to balance it, is there a method that doesn’t require such precision? Cheers

Comment: Can't you implement an auto-balance system and then just look at signal changes?

Comment: The 10^-4 ohms is in series with the capacitance or parallel?